# case=int(input()) File "<string>", line 0 ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the problem on codechef and i think i have tried enough to solve this but coming across various errors as i try to solve.This is i'm getting EOF while parsing error which i was not getting before.

```
case=int(input())
for i in range(case):
    n=int(input())
    l=[]
    r=[]
    lm=[]
    l=list(map(int,raw_input().split()))
    r=list(map(int,raw_input().split()))

    for j in range(n):
        lm.append(l[j]*r[j])
        print lm

    if lm.count(max(lm))>1:
        if r.count(max(r))>1:
            print lm.index(lm[0])+1
        else:

            print r.index(max(r))+1

     else:
         print lm.index(max(lm))+1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2.7 use raw_input() , later versions of python uses input()

and do you intentionally put for-else or is it a indentation problem?

Check this out
http://ideone.com/zcX7lA , 
maybe use pastebin.com or ideone.com to share code here

Comment: ohh sorry thats an indentation problem problem.

Comment: raw_input() is for getting string right.I'm taking an integer value.

Comment: `input` in Python 2 should be avoided, since it evaluates *arbitrary* inputs; it converts your value to an `int` *if* you enter a valid `int` literal. If the user types a string, it will attempt to produce the value of a variable with that name. Use `raw_input`, and pass its return value to `int` (and be prepared to catch any resulting `ValueError`s raised by `int`).

Comment: Thank you praveen and chepner for helping me !